# Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "phone" at /use_frameworks_beta_2/searchIndex to your security rules for better performance

Tags: ios, firebase, search, chat

I have an iOS app where I have to implement a simple chat between two users. I am registering the users to Firebase during app registration. All work good. But when I have to start a chat thread I am searching for a user using search indexes but I am getting following error:

Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "phone" at /use_frameworks_beta_2/searchIndex to your security rules for better performance
Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "email" at /use_frameworks_beta_2/searchIndex to your security rules for better performance
Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "name" at /use_frameworks_beta_2/searchIndex to your security rules for better performance

The Rules in Firebase console is as follows

{
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "searchIndex": {
                ".indexOn": ["email","phone","name"]
    }
}
}

Please help me fixing this error.

Answer (score 3):

The `.indexOn` specifier must be placed in the rules at the location containing the indexed keys.  Update your rules to place `.indexOn` at the correct location in the tree:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": true,
    ".read": true,
    "use_frameworks_beta_2": {
      "searchIndex ": {
        ".indexOn": ["email","phone","name"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But its not working :( I get the same error on console.

pulserx-148409
    + conversations
     -  use_frameworks_beta_2
         - searchIndex
            - 3386wcSL8WWgPU5XdUtimLtHlmN2
               email: "abc@gmail.com"
               name: "user996"
               phone: ""

This is the structure in firebase console.

Comment: Please update your post to show the rules after you updated as I suggested.